# How can I expand a Flutter horizontal ListView to take the remaining vertical space?

Tags: flutter, listview

My actual application involves a static portion of layout at the top of the screen, followed by a section that I would like to expand to fill the remainder of the vertical space.  This bottom section would ideally be a horizontal ListView that contains vertical ListViews.  To imagine this, think of a full-screen vertical ListView that contains an infinite number of cards, and then you can swipe left and right on the ListView to show different sets of cards.

In an ideal world, it would just be something like this:

```
return ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    // logic for selecting the right vertical stack
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(/* ... */);
      }
    );
  }
);
```

This throws because the horizontal ListView was given an unbounded height.  Because the remaining height is dynamic, I can't set a height directly.  Tricks like the following don't work:

- Wrapping the horizontal ListView in a Column + Expanded.  (flex + wrap are mutually exclusive)
- Using a LayoutBuilder.  (the vertical max size is infinity)
- Using MediaQuery.  (that's for the screen size, not remaining space)

Anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try to use mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, in the parent column

```
return Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
    const SizedBox(
      height: 100,
      child: Text('Hello World'),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              '  ${index}  ',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: That throws.  I'll paste (in three parts) the very descriptive reason the compiler gives:

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

Comment: Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.

Comment: Additionally, even if it didn't throw, I don't think it would do what I want, which is to have that top-level horizontal ListView take the remaining vertical space, even if the child (a vertical ListView) wouldn't intrinsically do that.   The whole space needs to be covered with a GestureDectector.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I hope you find the appropriate solution